# How does gcore look at another process' memory?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, process, operating-system

It is my understanding that memory virtualization in modern OSes (e.g. Linux) prevents a process from looking at another process' memory.  `gcore` is a program that specifically looks at another process' memory.  What am I misunderstanding about one (or both) of these statements?

Comment: Drivers....................

Comment: From a virtual memory standpoint, `gcore` cannot directly peek inside another processes memory. However, Linux provides `/proc/<pid>/mem`, which, given the proper permissions, will allow a program to read the memory space of another process, by presenting it as a "file" that can be read in the usual ways. That's completely outside of the virtual memory protection you're thinking about...